# passing multiple variable and data through a href

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have this:

```html
<button>
  <a href="/sendSessionConformationEmail?email=<%=data[i].EMAIL%>">
    SEND SESSION CONFORMATION EMAIL
  </a>
</button>
```

as you can see, I am trying to pass the variable `email`, with the data `<%=data[i].EMAIL%>`. I also need to pass `name`, with the data `<%=data[i].NAME%>`. How is it possible to do 2 at a time? Or even more. I tried to do it with a comma seperating them , but it didn't work.

Comment: Query parameters are separated with `&`. `?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3`

Comment: @Barmar aweosme thank you!